# java servlet redirect with attribute

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, redirect

I have servlet which depending on incoming URL performs different code:

```
if (URIstring.startsWith("/categories")) {
   //process request and send it to categories.jsp
} else if (URIstring.startsWith("/projects")) {
    //process request and send it to projects.jsp
}
```

Application starts from */context/categories* url and goes to first **if**.
On categories page, using form, I allow user to choose category. After user chose category, response to servlet comes like

```
/projects?category=1
```

Next I want to catch exceptions when user instead of numbers uses string or letters (which will generate **NumberFormatException** in *else if (URIstring.startsWith("/projects"))* part. I want to process this exception in following way: if servlet receives smth like

```
/projects?category=string
```

catch exception, redirect it back to categories page but with attribute set, like

```
error="You entered wrong input! Try again."
```

In *categories.jsp* file put

```
<c:out value="${error}"/>
```

In this case this line would be shown only in case of exception thrown. But how can I redirect between two jsps(of parts of **if** constructor) with attributes set. I have found only

```
else if (URIstring.startsWith("/projects")) {
    try {
        //process request and send it to projects.jsp
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        resp.sendRedirect("/context/categories"); 
    }
}
```

which redirects to needed **if** part and **JSP** but without my error attribute((( I tried:

```
req.setAttribute("error", "You entered wrong input! Try again.");
```

But it works for projects.jsp, not on redirected jsp((((

Answer (score 1):

`resp.sendRedirect` will terminate the current request and send a 302 redirect back to the client. Any attribute you have set on the request on the server side is then forgotten.

What you need to do is a server-side redirect, which can be accomplished with the `RequestDispatcher.forward` method. [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html)